# Calling virtual method from destructor - workaround?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I need to declare finalizing method `finalize()` for all descendants of the base class `Base`, that should be called during destruction, and my intent was to call pure `virtual void Base::finalize() = 0` from the `~Base()`, but c++ forbids such a thing. So my question is

How can we oblige descendants to do some finalizing work in right and preliminary defined way?

That code cannot be compiled:

```
#include <QDebug>
class Base {
        public:
            Base(){}
            virtual ~Base(){
                qDebug("deleting b");
                finalize();
            }
            virtual void finalize() = 0;

    };

class A : public Base
    {
    public:
        A(){}
        ~A(){}
        void finalize(){qDebug("called finalize in a");}
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Base *b = new A;
        delete b;
    }
```

If I make `Base::finalize()` not pure virtual, it is called from `~Base()` without dispatching to child since it have been already destructed.

I can call finalize() from child's destructor but question is how to force to do that. In other words my question is: is it possible to oblige people who will write descendants of the Base class to use finalizing method, well, in another way than commenting it in a documentation? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Destructors are the right place to release acquired resources, but each class is responsible to release its own resources. Resources acquired by `class A` should not (and just can not) be released by `class Base`.

Defining virtual destructors allows `class A`'s destructor to be called when deleting a pointer to `class Base` pointing to a `class A` object

```
Base* p = new A;
delete p; // Both A and Base destructors are sequencially called!
```

So to achieve proper resource release you just have to release each class' resources in its own destructor.

Comment: Ok, I see it, but my question is: is it possible to oblige people who will write descendants of the Base class to use finalizing method, well, in other way than comment it in a documentation? :)

Comment: It is possible but you may get compiler or run-time errors, because by the time `Base`'s destructor is called, `A`'s destructor has already been called so there is no `A` object on which to call your so-called `finalize()` method.

Comment: I've used your sample code and defined `finalize()` for `Base`, thus making it plain virtual (not pure). It compiles, but see what you get out of its execution http://ideone.com/opDXc

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying - it calls finalize from the base class, without dispatching (as could be expected) to A since it already have been destructed ))

Answer (score 3):

That's what a virtual destructor is for:

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   virtual ~B() {}
};
```

When an object of type `B` is destroyed, regardless of whether from a pointer to a `B` or a pointer to an `A`, both destructors will be called. First, `B::~B()` and then `A::~A()`.

Comment: @DmitryKachko just write a call to `unsubmit` in each destructor in which you want `unsubmit` to happen

Comment: Sure I can do that, but I cant oblige people who will use the A class as base

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How it could help me? I have void unsubmit() function which should called in each of descendats of A during destruction. Implementation of the Unsubmit is different for each of them. –

Comment: You could use typeid to only execute the unsubmit() in a virtual destructor if the instance is of that exact base class of which this destructor is. But this seems like an ugly solution.

Comment: @DmitryKachko so call unsubmit on each of the descendants' destructors. What's the problem with that? In C++, you get what you pay for.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if typeid info will be available for instance of D after virtual destructor of D has been executed and now it is in the virutal destructor of B (B being the base and D derived).

Comment: @Luchian Grigore Now I do like you say, sure. I'm wondering is any other solution exists. In other words my question is: is it possible to oblige people who will write descendants of the Base class to use finalizing method, well, in other way than comment it in a documentation? :)

Comment: @DmitryKachko make methods you want to be overriden pure virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Make the base class destructor pure virtual with a body, which should do exactly what you want.

Comment: To force derived classes to declare and implement a destructor of their own.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that the base was abstract (maybe a later edit).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the desctructor of Base? That what are destructors are made for.

Make search RAII and discover one of the finest things in c++.

Most people used to use other languages have to discover this. Resource management in c++ is completely different than in most other computer languages

Comment: What does RAII have to do with his question?